# Terminal lines being cut off?

Tags: command-line, xubuntu

I am running Xubuntu 16.04.3 using Xfce.

I am running the command

```
dpkg --list
```

When I try to scroll up to see the entire output, the first line I can see is....

```
ii  libfile-fcntllock-perl                                         0.22-3                               amd64
```

I don't think it is showing the entire output. Is there a setting where I can set the max length of the terminal output to more?

EDIT: I am running the default terminal for xfce. So fresh install, whatever comes up when I hit ctrl+alt+T. I guess that is xfce4-terminal.

Comment: Which terminal emulator? What's the output of `echo $COLUMNS $TERM`? Try running `COLUMNS=80 dpkg -l`. Add all information to the question, please.

Comment: When a command's output is very long, you usually want to pipe it to `less`...

Comment: @muru if it's Xubuntu's default terminal, it should be `xfce4-terminal`.

Comment: @DKBose could be xterm, which is also installed by default.

Comment: @muru true. OP needs to clarify.

Comment: And, re-looking at the question, could OP also want to increase the number of lines one could scroll back?