# XFCE get visual indication of current workspace

Tags: xfce, workspaces, xfce-panel, workspace-switcher

I just started embracing multiple workspaces, and I am using 3 of them. I am a very spatial oriented guy. So I really think of my workspaces as left center and right.

Is there any way I can enable a graphic that indicates the space relation ship of where I am switching my workspace to and from?

I have enabled the workspace switch panel item. But the highlight it gives for the current workspace is almost indistinguishable.

So basically what I am looking for, is the workspace switcher panel item, but one that actually visually indicates what workspace I am on.

Is there any way to enable something like this?

Comment: If you've solved https://askubuntu.com/questions/957544/terminal-lines-being-cut-off, please visit it and post your solution as an answer.

Comment: post relevant comments in relevant threads....

Comment: Have you tried changing the style?  menu > Settings > Appearance > Style tab.